# xampp-control "start" action button runs httpd.exe but won't update control window

Tags: apache

I have downloaded xampp-windows-x64-7.3.2-0-VC15-installer.exe and installed to c:\xampp\ folder as default.

Upon clicking on Start button to load the Apache server, I see that the control windows attempts to start Apache, but then nothing else populates in the status window. I checked httpd.exe, it is running. Checked localhost in a web browser, I see that the Apache server has been running, but control window still won't show the stop button, or indicate whether there was an error. I also found out that mysql is exhibiting the same problem, clicking the start button runs the mysql server but the control windows wouldn't update to show stop instead of start.

I also noticed that the ports become open when I hit the start button without update to the control window.

In addition, to stop the apache server, running xampp-stop.exe would eventually stop both mysql and apache simultaneously. The ports would close as expected afterwards.

PS: Running as administrator had same outcome.

Please can anyone suggest a solution to get the control window to update when the servers are running?

```
03:44:33 PM  [main]     Initializing Control Panel
03:44:33 PM  [main]     Windows Version: Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 64-bit
03:44:33 PM  [main]     XAMPP Version: 7.3.2
03:44:33 PM  [main]     Control Panel Version: 3.2.2  [ Compiled: Nov 12th 2015 ]
03:44:33 PM  [main]     You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for
03:44:33 PM  [main]     most application stuff but whenever you do something with services
03:44:33 PM  [main]     there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think 
03:44:33 PM  [main]     about running this application with administrator rights!
03:44:33 PM  [main]     XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
03:44:33 PM  [main]     Checking for prerequisites
03:44:33 PM  [main]     All prerequisites found
03:44:33 PM  [main]     Initializing Modules
03:44:33 PM  [main]     Starting Check-Timer
03:44:33 PM  [main]     Control Panel Ready
03:49:50 PM  [Apache]   Attempting to start Apache app...
```

[xampp-control.exe starts apache and mysql but wouldn't update app on screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEc7n.png)

Enabling the "Show debug information" in the control panel configuration windows, shows that httpd.exe returns 0 to the control window.

```
04:20:00 PM  [main]     Initializing Control Panel
04:20:00 PM  [main]     Windows Version: Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 64-bit
04:20:00 PM  [main]     XAMPP Version: 7.3.2
04:20:00 PM  [main]     Control Panel Version: 3.2.2  [ Compiled: Nov 12th 2015 ]
04:20:00 PM  [main]     You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for
04:20:00 PM  [main]     most application stuff but whenever you do something with services
04:20:00 PM  [main]     there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think 
04:20:00 PM  [main]     about running this application with administrator rights!
04:20:00 PM  [main]     XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
04:20:00 PM  [main]     Checking for prerequisites
04:20:00 PM  [main]     All prerequisites found
04:20:00 PM  [main]     Initializing Modules
04:20:00 PM  [Apache]   Initializing module...
04:20:00 PM  [Apache]   Checking for module existence...
04:20:00 PM  [Apache]   Checking for required tools...
04:20:00 PM  [Apache]   Checking for service (name="Apache2.4"): Service not installed
04:20:00 PM  [Apache]   Service Path: Service Not Installed
04:20:00 PM  [Apache]   Checking default ports...
04:20:00 PM  [mysql]    Initializing module...
04:20:00 PM  [mysql]    Checking for module existence...
04:20:00 PM  [mysql]    Checking for required tools...
04:20:00 PM  [mysql]    Checking for service (name="mysql"): Service not installed
04:20:00 PM  [mysql]    Service Path: Service Not Installed
04:20:00 PM  [mysql]    Checking default ports...
04:20:00 PM  [filezilla]    Initializing module...
04:20:00 PM  [filezilla]    Checking for module existence...
04:20:00 PM  [filezilla]    Checking for required tools...
04:20:00 PM  [filezilla]    Checking for service (name="FileZillaServer"): Service not installed
04:20:00 PM  [filezilla]    Service Path: Service Not Installed
04:20:00 PM  [filezilla]    Checking default ports...
04:20:00 PM  [mercury]  Initializing module...
04:20:00 PM  [mercury]  Checking for module existence...
04:20:00 PM  [mercury]  Checking for required tools...
04:20:00 PM  [mercury]  Checking default ports...
04:20:00 PM  [Tomcat]   Initializing module...
04:20:00 PM  [Tomcat]   Checking for module existence...
04:20:00 PM  [Tomcat]   Checking for required tools...
04:20:00 PM  [Tomcat]   Checking for service (name="Tomcat7"): Service not installed
04:20:00 PM  [Tomcat]   Service Path: Service Not Installed
04:20:00 PM  [Tomcat]   Checking default ports...
04:20:00 PM  [main]     Starting Check-Timer
04:20:00 PM  [main]     Control Panel Ready
04:20:44 PM  [Apache]   Checking default ports...
04:20:44 PM  [Apache]   Attempting to start Apache app...
04:20:44 PM  [Apache]   Executing "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe"
04:20:44 PM  [Apache]   Return code: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

So I went with installing the services, that is done by running the xampp-control.exe as administrator then clicking on the X boxes on the left of each apache and mysql.
Then clicking on start button eventually updates the control window.

[xampp-control window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88V5s.png)

```
.... //omitting extra lines above.
04:39:16 PM  [Apache]   Attempting to start Apache service...
04:39:16 PM  [Apache]   Executing "net start "Apache2.4""
04:39:17 PM  [Apache]   Status change detected: running
04:39:19 PM  [Apache]   Return code: 0
04:39:29 PM  [mysql]    Checking default ports...
04:39:29 PM  [mysql]    Attempting to start MySQL service...
04:39:29 PM  [mysql]    Executing "net start "mysql""
04:39:30 PM  [mysql]    Status change detected: running
04:39:32 PM  [mysql]    Return code: 0
```